# sending a scheduled message with cron & node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, discord.js

I'm new to using node.js, cron, and picking up Javascript again from a very basic knowledge of it, so please bear with me. Thank you!

My objective here is to run a Discord bot that sends a specific message at a specific time daily on my server. A lot of users here recommended using cron for that kind of function, so I installed it and tried using fragments of what they suggested.

```
const cron = require('cron');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { token, guildid, channelid } = require('./config.json');

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Good to go.');
});

const scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob('00 00 08 * * *', () => {
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildid);
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelid);
channel.send('My Message');
});


scheduledMessage.start()
```

The error I'm getting is
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined*, although I'm pretty sure I might be having more issues than that and I don't think I'm using the cron job properly at all.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the problem is with cron, the problem is that Discord cannot find the channel you're referencing. Double-check the `channelid` variable to make sure it's a valid Channel ID

Answer (score 0):

You could go in a different direction and completely just use node:

```js
 var countDownDate = new Date("October 2, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
 
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
 
    var timeDifference = countDownDate - currentTime;
 
    // If the count down is over, send the message
    if (timeDifference == 0) {
        let channel client.channels.cache.get('channelID');
        channel.send('messageHere')
    }
}
```